# Grammatical variation between Attic Greek prose authors

Tags: greek, variation

I'm interested in the grammatical variation that is found between prose writers in what is putatively a single dialect of Greek, Attic. Such variation exists on various levels:

- Phonology: e.g., some writers write -ττ-, others -σσ-; Thucydides writes ξύν where most writers prefer σύν.
- Morphology: e.g., desideratives in -σέω are fairly productive in Thucydides, but not in most other writers.
- Morphosyntax: e.g., Xenophon has purpose clauses with ὅπως + fut. ind., where other writers tend to use the subjunctive.

I want to identify such distinguishing features for the major Attic prose writers. I assume this has been done for different authors to different extents. Where would I find such information about specific writers (presumably some commentaries might discuss this, but which ones?), or even better, a comparative study?

Answer (score 3):

For a general introduction to the ways that Greek dialect and style interact over time, Geoffrey Horrock's [*Greek: a History of the Language and its Speakers*](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1405134151.html) will have the best overall coverage.  A lighter (though still fairly technical) approach is in Leonard Palmer's *The Greek Language*.

There's also a website for an advanced course in Greek Rhetoric and Prose Style which could perhaps be organized better, but has a lot of good info: [Greek 701](http://greek701.ws.gc.cuny.edu).  The links off the syllabus have the most information.